# Decoding "prog > file 2>&1"

Tags: shell, io-redirection, stdout, stdin

I am having some difficulty understanding the construct `prog > file 2>&1`. I have read that it means "Send *stdout* and *stderr* to file". But my question is how?

I understand that `prog > file` basically sends *stdout* to file. I also understand that `prog 2>&1` means that the *stderr* should be sent to *stdout*. But I am not able to connect the dots for  `prog > file 2>&1`. Can experts here help me decode this.

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/redirecting-stderr-to-stdout/

Comment: Also, this comment gives the connecting dots that you are looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876239/bash-redirect-and-append-both-stdout-and-stderr#comment684047_876242

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just have to read it left to right:

- `> file` --> redirect all thing from `stdout` to `file`.(You can imagine you have a link, point-to-point from `stdout` to
  `file`)
- `2>&1` --> redirect all thing from `stderr` to `stdout`, which is now pointed to `file`.

So conclusion:

```
stderr --> stdout --> file
```

You can see a good reference [here](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/bash-one-liners-explained-part-three/).

Comment: @jordanm: No, redirection is processed from left to right.

Comment: I just checked the manpage again and you are correct.

Comment: @terdon yeah, for that reason I always thought it processed right to left but the bash manpage explicitly says "Redirections are  processed in the order they appear, from left to right."

Comment: @jordanm and Gnouc huh? Then why does `perl -le 'print STDERR error; print STDOUT out' 2>&1 >/dev/null` return `error`? It looks like it's read from right to left, first it redirects stdout to `/dev/null` and _then_ redirects stderr to &1.

Comment: @terdon: Because When you `print STDERR` in `perl`, `stderr` is "connecting" to `stdout`, and `stdout` have not redirected to `/dev/null` yet. It like yout need `> file` before `2>&1`. And you can think in your case, if `right to left`, first `stdout` is pointed to `/dev/null`, then `stderr` is pointed to `stdout`, which is `/dev/null` now, so why does "error" is printed?

Answer (score 2):

What is it you are missing? You seem to have understood everything. The `> file` sends the output to `file` and `2>&1` sends standard error to standard output. The final result is that both stderr and stdout are sent to `file`.

To illustrate, consider this simple Perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
print STDERR "Standard Error\n";
print STDOUT "Standard Output\n";
```

Now have a look at its output:

```sh
$ foo.pl     ## Both error and out are printed to the terminal
Standard Error
Standard Output

$ foo.pl 2>file  ## Error is redirected to file, only output is shown
Standard Output  
$ foo.pl 1>file ## Output is redirected to file, only error is shown
Standard Error

$ foo.pl 1>file 2>&1 ## Everything is sent to file, nothing is shown.
```